# How to use an XML Schema to validate @ResponseBody marshalled by JAXB

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, integration-testing

I have a system returning a lot of XMLs using @ResponseBody and @XmlElement marshalling (JAXB).

What is the best way to validate the resulting XML using a created Schema?

I still need to run through the elements and test those, but a XML Schema validation would make the second part really easy.

Answer (score 2):

Spring makes this easy for you (assuming you use the Jaxb2Marshaller):

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
  <property name="schema" value="file:/some/path/schema.xsd"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I am pretty new to Spring, but how do I specify which xsd to which `@ResponseBody` which is what I need to test (controller returns a marshalled XML based on combined models)

Comment: Oki, I've added `<bean id="marshaller" class="test.project.util.ClasspathScanningJaxb2Marshaller"><property name="schema" value="classpath:service.xsd" /><property name="basePackages" value="test.project" /></bean>`, instead of adding `classesToBeBound`, I have used http://www.walgemoed.org/2010/12/jaxb2-spring-ws/. However, everything runs nicely, in the sense, even invalid xsd does not give any error message

Comment: Check out http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-restful/ (Listing 4) for an example how to set up a http marshaling converter and give it the above marshaller.

Comment: Mm... I'll have a look it at. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Setup XSD schema for JAXB marshaller and unmarshaller:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
InputStream schemaStream = openMySchemaFileStream();
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(schemaStream));    
marshaller.setSchema(schema);
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

Validate XML string by unmarshalling it:

```
Reader reader = new StringReader(xml);
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(reader);
unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, YourJAXBClass.class);
```

Validate JAXB object by marshalling to SAX' DefaultHandler, that does nothing:

```
marshaller.marshal(obj, new DefaultHandler());
```

Comment: Uhm, how do I connect this to Spring and the result in `@ResponseBody`?